# Moving averages with nulls in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

So I have three columns: a location id, a year and a height.

I want to calculate a five-year rolling average. But, if there are not five years worth of data, I do not want a result.

I've been learning about using OVER. And I've seen other questions dealing with this topic, but couldn't find a solution for my issue.

Here's where I stand:

```
select locationID, year_num, height_num2, 
         avg(cast(height_num2 as float)) over (PARTITION BY locationID
                                                ORDER BY year_num
                                                ROWS 4 PRECEDING) as FiveYearRollingAverage
from combined;
```

And now I'm stumped on how best to approach this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to just add a counter, so as to know the number of records involved in the average. If they are 5, then select the record containing the rolling average using an outer query:

```
SELECT locationID, year_num, FiveYearRollingAverage
FROM (
SELECT locationID, year_num, 
       AVG(CAST(height_num2 AS FLOAT)) OVER (PARTITION BY locationID ORDER BY year_num ROWS 4 PRECEDING) FiveYearRollingAverage,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY locationID ORDER BY year_num ROWS 4 PRECEDING) yearsCount
FROM @combined) u
WHERE u.yearsCount = 5
```

With this input:

```
DECLARE @combined TABLE (locationID INT, year_num INT, height_num2 INT)

INSERT @combined VALUES
(1, 2009, 1),
(1, 2010, 4),
(1, 2011, 3),
(1, 2012, 2),
(1, 2013, 5),
(1, 2014, 7),
(2, 2014, 2),
(2, 2015, 1),
(2, 2016, 4),
(2, 2017, 3)
```

you get this output:

```
locationID  year_num    FiveYearRollingAverage
----------------------------------------------
1           2013         3 
1           2014         4,2
```

There is no output for locationID = 2, since only 4 years are available for this ID.